# Drawing a part of a cylinder

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd, shading, circles

Here is the drawing I want to draw:

> [image]

I want to draw this part of the cylinder and a square with internal shading (I do not want the dotted line inside the square, it was a typo)

Can someone help me in drawing this please?

Comment: Kindly have a look here: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf . I suggest skimming through the minimal introduction, first. // Also please check out the links to the right, namend "Related", as well as your own tags: just click on them.

Comment: @MS-SPO but I do not want to shade my cylinder, that is what is in related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with something like this:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, patterns, patterns.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) [draw,shape=ellipse,minimum width=2cm] {};
\node at (0,-3cm) [draw,shape=ellipse,minimum width=2cm] {};
\draw (-1,0)node[left]{$\alpha,x$} --node[left]{$c$} (-1,-3)node[left]{$f(x)\equiv y$};

\draw [pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance=5pt]},pattern color=blue] (3,0)node[left]{$x$} --node[left]{$c$} ++(0,-3)node[left]{$y$} --++(6.28,0)node[right]{$y$} --node[right]{$c$} ++(0,3)node[right]{$x$} --cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How about the shading of the square?

Comment: I am also using document class book, will the code still applicable?

Comment: @Happy - I've added the shading part, and the code should work fine inside the book class, just remove first line.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [3dtools](https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools). Note that, ingenral, the vertical segment is not path from the point `(0,-r,0` to `(0,r,0)`. I draw red  this segment in this code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,border= 3.14 mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,3dtools}% https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[3d/install view={phi=70,psi=0,theta=65},line join = round, line cap = round,declare function={h=5;r=3;}]
\path 
(0,0,0) coordinate (O)
(0,0,h) coordinate (O'); 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myscreenex}{TDunit("(0,0,1)x(nscreenx,nscreeny,nscreenz)")}
\path[3d coordinate={(L)=(O)-r*(\myscreenex)},3d coordinate={(R)=(L) + (O')}];
\draw[3d/visible] (O') circle[radius = r] (O) circle[radius = r];       
\draw[3d/visible] (R) node[left]{$\alpha,x$} --node[left]{$c$} (L)node[left]{$f(x)\equiv y$};
\draw[red] (0,-r,0) -- (0,-r,h);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]